# Trouble Deploying Springboot War to Openshift jbossews (Tomcat 7)

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, openshift

I currently have a working very basic spring-boot application running with tomcat on my dev machine.  When deploying to tomcat 7 on openshift, all static resources fail to load (css and js).  Also my rest endpoints are not reachable.  It's probably some sort of context configuration I need to setup on openshift but I'm not sure how to do that as it seems it would be openshift specific?  My other thought is that maybe it's just not compatible with a springboot war?  Again the application starts right up on a tomcat instance I have locally with no special configurations (meaning I'm configuring everything by letting springboot do it's thing), but once depolyed to openshift I can see 404's when loading js and css and when trying to hit rest endpoints.

Static content is currently located under src/main/resources/static/ as per springboot standards

```
i.e. /src/main/resources/static/js
     /src/main/resources/static/css
```

I am using relative paths in my webpages:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

I can provide more information as needed, and yes I have extended SpringBootServletInitializer, but it would appear that openshift tomcat may be overriding my changes.

Also I should note I am using the compiled war approach, which is creating a new git project (clone) from openshift, deleting the .pom and src folder, and adding my ROOT.war under webapps.  I am seeing my html, just not the CSS and JS that goes along with it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The "standard" is `src/main/resources/static` not `/src/main/java/resources/static`... Those are quite different paths and the one you specify to use isn't one that will be included (maven by default ignores non java resources in `src/main/java`.

Comment: Your right I'm actually putting resources in src/main/resources/static I will edit the above.  Still does not work though.  I stood up an aws ec2 instance and got it working over there, maybe I'll try to figure out openshift again later.